# Using alternate away instead of staging table to join data to itself

Tags: sql-server

Trying to Optimize my code not to using a temptable, im new to sql server, the code i wrote gives me the info i need

```
Create table FI (
tipodoc numeric,
nmdoc varchar(20),
fno numeric,
rdata datetime,
fnoft numeric,
design varchar(60);

Insert into Fi (tipodoc ,
nmdoc,
fno,
rdata ,
fnoft ,
design)
values(1,'FT','18',2017-31-12,null,null),
(2,'NC',1,2018-31-12,18,'FT 18 18-12-2017'),
(1,'FT',1,2018-01-01,null,null),
(2,'NC',1,2018-31-12,1,'FT 1 01-01-2018'), 
(1,'FT',2,2018-31-12,null,null),
(2,'NC',1,2019-31-12,5,'FT 2 31-12-2018')

select
Cod_final = convert(int,fi.fnoft+fi.tipodoc+fi.rdata),
fi.tipodoc,
fi.nmdoc,
fi.fno,
fi.rdata, 
fi.fnoft, 
ltrim(rtrim(CONVERT(varchar(30),replace(right(design,10 ),'.','-')))) as Ftdata
into tempFI
from fi
where fi.nmdoc Like '%Credito' and design like '%factura%';

select
tempFI.Cod_final,
fi.nmdoc,
fi.fno,
convert(date,fi.rdata) as DataDoc,
Fi.fnoft,
tempFI.rdata, 
tempfi.Ftdata
from fi
inner join tempfi on fi.fnoft=tempFI.fnoft
where convert(int,fi.fnoft+fi.tipodoc+fi.rdata) = tempFI.Cod_final  
and fi.tipodoc =3 and tempfi.ftdata like '%-%-%'
order by tempFI.Cod_final

go
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempfi
```

raw data 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VCd8ZQVt6ztLNNhUb-FRj1WIAGW8zYZP3AZbx3GaGTs/edit?usp=sharing

[Data Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKH8G.png)

Brief explanation of what i pretend and i have done

Tempfi.cod_final - since the fnoft, tipodoc repeat themselves over the years 
the same fnoft and tipodoc( this is associated with nmdoc there is a number associated for document type )  this are both int , so i converted rdata which is datatime when document is created and this is my new number so i can identify correctly.

fno and fnoft - cod_final 42726 is fno 8 and was originited from fnoft 1268 is the same number in fno from different document type tipodoc

tempfi.rdata - i was testing in getting the correct value for tempfi.codfinal date time when document was created, which i failed miserably

tempfi.FTdata . is a string that contains the number of fnoft and date of creation so my tempfi.rdata should be the same as tempfi.ftdata

thanks for your help , and im sorry if this is a bit messy

**Update** 
**So after reading about CTE i Have built this**

```
with cte_fi2 as
(
    select
        Cod_final = convert(int,fi.fnoft+fi.tipodoc+fi.rdata),
        fi.tipodoc,
        fi.nmdoc,
        fi.fno,
        fi.rdata,
        fi.eteliquido        
    from fi
    where fi.tipodoc = 1
),

cte_fi as 
( 
    select
        Cod_final = convert(int,fi.fnoft+fi.tipodoc+fi.rdata),
        fi.tipodoc,
        fi.nmdoc,
        fi.fno,
        fi.rdata,
        fi.fnoft, 
        ltrim(rtrim(CONVERT(varchar(30),replace(right(design,10 ),'.','-')))) as Ftdata
    from fi
    where fi.tipodoc=3 and design like '%factura%'
)



select
    fi.nmdoc,
    fi.fno as NºNC,
    convert(date,fi.rdata) as DataNC,
    Fi.fnoft as NºFT,
    cte_fi2.rdata as DataFTcte2,
    cte_fi.ftdata,

from fi
    inner join cte_fi on fi.fno=cte_fi.fno 
    inner join cte_fi2 on fi.fno = cte_fi2.fno
where  fi.tipodoc =3 and cte_fi.ftdata like '%-%-%'
order by cte_fi.Cod_final
```

Im still doing something wrong with with ct2_fi2.rdata it should return same value as cte_fi.tdata, ct2_fi2.rdata is date creation of fi.tipodoc = 1, 
guess im doing something wrong in the inner join.  i dont understand what yet

```
 Nmdoc     FNo   fi.rdata   Fnoft  cte_fi2.rdata   cte_fi.ftdata
   NC       3     2013-02-08  0     08-02-2013     2016-01-04
```

Output

Comment: FYI, an object called `tempFI` isn;t a temporary table. Temporary table names begin with a hash (`#`) and persist only for the duration of the connection they were created in. What you are doing is creating an actual table in your database; what is more commonly known as a "staging table".

Comment: Could you post some sample data and expected results here? Likely this is something that could easily be achieved with a CTE.

Comment: its in data Output

Comment: That's an image, and only 1 image. There's no sample data there for us to make use of, and images aren't helpful to the volunteers here anyway I'm afraid; we can't copy an image and use the data inside it.

Comment: theres a sample of raw data add

Comment: Not many people are going to download a spreadsheet to get to a few rows of sample data. Just post the table definition (create table statement) and the data (insert statements) in your question.

Comment: I don't think you need to use a persistent table here, you are just joining the table to itself. You could do this with a cte just as easily.

Comment: thanks guys , updated my post and im sorry for the trouble , from what you said about CTE ,and what i read this could resolve my problem without creating a table